# BigQuery SQL Regex_extract repeated pattern

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

New to regexp,  below is the sample query and our try as below

```
with string_tbl as 
( select 'https://www.this-is-abcd.com/<some_text>/ab.cd.ef.gh.ij/123456.csv' str
```

union all
select 'https://www.this-is-pqrs.com/<some_text>/ab.abc.ef.gh.ij/123456.csv' str
union all
select 'https://www.this-is-pqrs.com/<some_text>/ab.abd.ef.gh.ij/123456.csv' str
union all
select 'https://www.this-is-abcd.com/<some_text>/ab.abc.ef.gh.ij/123456.csv' str

)
select REGEXP_EXTRACT(string_tbl.str, r"ab[^/]*") from string_tbl;

**output we are getting:**

```
abcd.com
ab.abc.ef.gh.ij
ab.abd.ef.gh.ij
abcd.com
```

**Required output:**

```
ab.abc.ef.gh.ij
ab.abc.ef.gh.ij
ab.abd.ef.gh.ij
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below

```
select regexp_extract(string_tbl.str, r"/(ab[^/]*)") 
from string_tbl
```

with output

[image]